# how long will the items stay in shopping cart for logged in customers?

Tags: cart, session

Since so many customers added items in shopping cart but not checkout, the stock will be hold by this situation. How can i limit the time of items staying in customers's cart?

Setting Quote Lifetime setting->Checkout->Quote Lifetime (days) is a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the customer is logged, the products will remain in the cart forever. Well...at least the customer goes to the checkout process.
But this should not influence the stock. The stock is decreased only after the checkout process.
So if the user has a product in the cart for X days, and in the mean time everything that is in stock is sold, when the customer tries to checkout he will get an error message saying that at least one product is out of stock.

The `Quote Lifetime` setting i think is for guest carts. They will be treated as abandoned after the X number of days are ended and there is no change to the quote.

Comment: Quote lifetime is not for guest carts. In fact, quote lifetime only seems to affect quotes that have been converted to orders, or potentially converted to orders (if the customer goes to a third party website to pay). See `is_active` filter in `Mage_Sales_Model_Observer::cleanExpiredQuotes`.

Comment: Also see http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/sales/shopping-cart-quote-lifetime.html
The documentation is pretty cryptic though...

Comment: Means that product is save in cart lifetime?